# android Volley Gson not work

Tags: android, gson

android gson Volley not work how to handle i'm not able to handle please Help me

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was
>   BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

```
public class model {


    private String status;
    private PagingBean paging;
    private List<DataBean> data;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public PagingBean getPaging() {
        return paging;
    }

    public void setPaging(PagingBean paging) {
        this.paging = paging;
    }

    public List<DataBean> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<DataBean> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static class PagingBean {
        /**
         * total_count : 279
         * limit : 20
         * offset : 0
         */

        private String total_count;
        private int limit;
        private int offset;

        public String getTotal_count() {
            return total_count;
        }

        public void setTotal_count(String total_count) {
            this.total_count = total_count;
        }

        public int getLimit() {
            return limit;
        }

        public void setLimit(int limit) {
            this.limit = limit;
        }

        public int getOffset() {
            return offset;
        }

        public void setOffset(int offset) {
            this.offset = offset;
        }
    }

    public static class DataBean {

        @SerializedName("ArticleID")
        private String ArticleID;
        @SerializedName("TopicID")
        private String TopicID;
        private String EntID;
        private String CompID;
        private String ArticleOwnerUsrID;
        private String ArticleType;
        private String ArticleTitle;
        private String ArticleThumb;
        private Object ArticleImg;
        private String ArticleTopImg;
        private String ArticleSum;
        private String ArticleExtUrl;
        private String CommentCnt;
        private String ReplyCnt;
        private String ArticleCreatedBy;
        private String ArticleModDt;
        private String ArticleCreatedDt;
        private String ArticleTotalRating;
        private String ArticleRatingCnt;
        private String ArticleViewCnt;
        private Object UsrFileID;
        private String GroupID;
        private String GroupAddTyp;
        private String ArticleAddTyp;
        private String meta;
        private String meta_image;
        private Object ArticleSubType;
        private String Language;
        private String TopicNm;
        private String ArticleTopImgThumb;
        private int ReadTime;
        private String UsrPicture;
        private int LikeFlag;
        private int Likes;
        private String isFavourite;
        private List<?> Attachment;
        private List<TagNmBean> TagNm;

        public String getArticleID() {
            return ArticleID;
        }

        public void setArticleID(String ArticleID) {
            this.ArticleID = ArticleID;
        }

        public String getTopicID() {
            return TopicID;
        }

        public void setTopicID(String TopicID) {
            this.TopicID = TopicID;
        }

        public String getEntID() {
            return EntID;
        }

        public void setEntID(String EntID) {
            this.EntID = EntID;
        }

        public String getCompID() {
            return CompID;
        }

        public void setCompID(String CompID) {
            this.CompID = CompID;
        }

        public String getArticleOwnerUsrID() {
            return ArticleOwnerUsrID;
        }

        public void setArticleOwnerUsrID(String ArticleOwnerUsrID) {
            this.ArticleOwnerUsrID = ArticleOwnerUsrID;
        }

        public String getArticleType() {
            return ArticleType;
        }

        public void setArticleType(String ArticleType) {
            this.ArticleType = ArticleType;
        }

        public String getArticleTitle() {
            return ArticleTitle;
        }

        public void setArticleTitle(String ArticleTitle) {
            this.ArticleTitle = ArticleTitle;
        }

        public String getArticleThumb() {
            return ArticleThumb;
        }

        public void setArticleThumb(String ArticleThumb) {
            this.ArticleThumb = ArticleThumb;
        }

        public Object getArticleImg() {
            return ArticleImg;
        }

        public void setArticleImg(Object ArticleImg) {
            this.ArticleImg = ArticleImg;
        }

        public String getArticleTopImg() {
            return ArticleTopImg;
        }

        public void setArticleTopImg(String ArticleTopImg) {
            this.ArticleTopImg = ArticleTopImg;
        }

        public String getArticleSum() {
            return ArticleSum;
        }

        public void setArticleSum(String ArticleSum) {
            this.ArticleSum = ArticleSum;
        }

        public String getArticleExtUrl() {
            return ArticleExtUrl;
        }

        public void setArticleExtUrl(String ArticleExtUrl) {
            this.ArticleExtUrl = ArticleExtUrl;
        }

        public String getCommentCnt() {
            return CommentCnt;
        }

        public void setCommentCnt(String CommentCnt) {
            this.CommentCnt = CommentCnt;
        }

        public String getReplyCnt() {
            return ReplyCnt;
        }

        public void setReplyCnt(String ReplyCnt) {
            this.ReplyCnt = ReplyCnt;
        }

        public String getArticleCreatedBy() {
            return ArticleCreatedBy;
        }

        public void setArticleCreatedBy(String ArticleCreatedBy) {
            this.ArticleCreatedBy = ArticleCreatedBy;
        }

        public String getArticleModDt() {
            return ArticleModDt;
        }

        public void setArticleModDt(String ArticleModDt) {
            this.ArticleModDt = ArticleModDt;
        }

        public String getArticleCreatedDt() {
            return ArticleCreatedDt;
        }

        public void setArticleCreatedDt(String ArticleCreatedDt) {
            this.ArticleCreatedDt = ArticleCreatedDt;
        }

        public String getArticleTotalRating() {
            return ArticleTotalRating;
        }

        public void setArticleTotalRating(String ArticleTotalRating) {
            this.ArticleTotalRating = ArticleTotalRating;
        }

        public String getArticleRatingCnt() {
            return ArticleRatingCnt;
        }

        public void setArticleRatingCnt(String ArticleRatingCnt) {
            this.ArticleRatingCnt = ArticleRatingCnt;
        }

        public String getArticleViewCnt() {
            return ArticleViewCnt;
        }

        public void setArticleViewCnt(String ArticleViewCnt) {
            this.ArticleViewCnt = ArticleViewCnt;
        }

        public Object getUsrFileID() {
            return UsrFileID;
        }

        public void setUsrFileID(Object UsrFileID) {
            this.UsrFileID = UsrFileID;
        }

        public String getGroupID() {
            return GroupID;
        }

        public void setGroupID(String GroupID) {
            this.GroupID = GroupID;
        }

        public String getGroupAddTyp() {
            return GroupAddTyp;
        }

        public void setGroupAddTyp(String GroupAddTyp) {
            this.GroupAddTyp = GroupAddTyp;
        }

        public String getArticleAddTyp() {
            return ArticleAddTyp;
        }

        public void setArticleAddTyp(String ArticleAddTyp) {
            this.ArticleAddTyp = ArticleAddTyp;
        }

        public String getMeta() {
            return meta;
        }

        public void setMeta(String meta) {
            this.meta = meta;
        }

        public String getMeta_image() {
            return meta_image;
        }

        public void setMeta_image(String meta_image) {
            this.meta_image = meta_image;
        }

        public Object getArticleSubType() {
            return ArticleSubType;
        }

        public void setArticleSubType(Object ArticleSubType) {
            this.ArticleSubType = ArticleSubType;
        }

        public String getLanguage() {
            return Language;
        }

        public void setLanguage(String Language) {
            this.Language = Language;
        }

        public String getTopicNm() {
            return TopicNm;
        }

        public void setTopicNm(String TopicNm) {
            this.TopicNm = TopicNm;
        }

        public String getArticleTopImgThumb() {
            return ArticleTopImgThumb;
        }

        public void setArticleTopImgThumb(String ArticleTopImgThumb) {
            this.ArticleTopImgThumb = ArticleTopImgThumb;
        }

        public int getReadTime() {
            return ReadTime;
        }

        public void setReadTime(int ReadTime) {
            this.ReadTime = ReadTime;
        }

        public String getUsrPicture() {
            return UsrPicture;
        }

        public void setUsrPicture(String UsrPicture) {
            this.UsrPicture = UsrPicture;
        }

        public int getLikeFlag() {
            return LikeFlag;
        }

        public void setLikeFlag(int LikeFlag) {
            this.LikeFlag = LikeFlag;
        }

        public int getLikes() {
            return Likes;
        }

        public void setLikes(int Likes) {
            this.Likes = Likes;
        }

        public String getIsFavourite() {
            return isFavourite;
        }

        public void setIsFavourite(String isFavourite) {
            this.isFavourite = isFavourite;
        }

        public List<?> getAttachment() {
            return Attachment;
        }

        public void setAttachment(List<?> Attachment) {
            this.Attachment = Attachment;
        }

        public List<TagNmBean> getTagNm() {
            return TagNm;
        }

        public void setTagNm(List<TagNmBean> TagNm) {
            this.TagNm = TagNm;
        }

        public static class TagNmBean {
            /**
             * ArticleID : 10193
             * TagID : 1048
             * TagNm : RBI
             */

            private String ArticleID;
            private String TagID;
            private String TagNm;

            public String getArticleID() {
                return ArticleID;
            }

            public void setArticleID(String ArticleID) {
                this.ArticleID = ArticleID;
            }

            public String getTagID() {
                return TagID;
            }

            public void setTagID(String TagID) {
                this.TagID = TagID;
            }

            public String getTagNm() {
                return TagNm;
            }

            public void setTagNm(String TagNm) {
                this.TagNm = TagNm;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Volley Call

```
public void HubApi(){

    requestParse.postJson(url, new RequestParse.VolleyCallBackPost() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {

            Log.i("=========RESPONSE",result);
            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
            gson = gsonBuilder.create();


            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<model>>(){}.getType();
            Collection<model> enums = gson.fromJson(result, collectionType);

        }
        @Override
        public void onRequestError(String errorMessage) {

        }
        @Override
        public Map OnParam(Map<String, String> params) {
            params.put("offset","0");
            params.put("viewtype","all");
            params.put("limit","20");
            params.put("access_token","ac354baf58cb25ef872056f6950cfea5780ccec04dc368642948cbdb7a4a8b28:8437385c8638a834");
            return params;

        }
    });

}
```

Response

```
"status": "success",
 "data": [

     {
     "ArticleID": "399287",
     "TopicID": "669",
     "EntID": "754",
     "CompID": "0",
     "ArticleOwnerUsrID": "38458",
     "ArticleType": "1",
     "ArticleTitle": "Want to be an ;s how to start your own company",
     "ArticleThumb": "https:\/\/25fbe163291a88330f29e0272126c4bd.jpg",
     "ArticleImg": null,
     "ArticleTopImg": "https:\/\/n\/035ad7c65b8f53d63f0c718116f02b8c.jpg",
     "ArticleSum": "Here are 10 ustarting their own company.",
     "ArticleExtUrl": "",
     "CommentCnt": "54",
     "ReplyCnt": "0",
     "ArticleCreatedBy": "gt",
     "ArticleModDt": "2016-11-14 10:26:08",
     "ArticleCreatedDt": "2016-09-21 06:30:00",
     "ArticleTotalRating": "0",
     "ArticleRatingCnt": "0",
     "ArticleViewCnt": "9",
     "UsrFileID": null,
     "GroupID": "0",
     "GroupAddTyp": "1",
     "ArticleAddTyp": "1",
     "meta": "[]",
     "meta_image": "",
     "ArticleSubType": null,
     "Language": "en",
     "Attachment": [],
     "TopicNm": "Entrepreneurship",
     "TagNm": [
         {
             "ArticleID": "3287",
             "TagID": "1195",
             "TagNm": "Array"
         }
     ],
     "ArticleTopImgThumb": "https:5ad7c65b8f53d63f0c718116f02b8c_t.jpg",
     "ReadTime": 6,
     "UsrPicture": "https:\/ofile\/MB.png",
     "LikeFlag": 1,
     "Likes": 10,
     "isFavourite": "yes"
   },
```

Comment: are you got response?

Comment: yes I get Response log is print

Comment: can you put response here? may b response is not proper

Comment: some node removed b'coz big size

Comment: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ use this link to check json response is proper or not

Comment: Json response right

Comment: can I write other way Gson

Comment: try this way 
Gson gson=new Gson();
DomainEntity domainEntity=gson.fromJson(response,DomainEntity.class);

Comment: not work please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your response this way. Then apply

```
Gson gson=new Gson(); Example example =gson.fromJson(response,Example .class);
```

here you found three class
Datum.java, Example.java, Tagnm.java rename according to your requirement.

-----------------------------------com.example.Datum.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


public class Datum {

@SerializedName("ArticleID")
@Expose
private String articleID;
@SerializedName("TopicID")
@Expose
private String topicID;
@SerializedName("EntID")
@Expose
private String entID;
@SerializedName("CompID")
@Expose
private String compID;
@SerializedName("ArticleOwnerUsrID")
@Expose
private String articleOwnerUsrID;
@SerializedName("ArticleType")
@Expose
private String articleType;
@SerializedName("ArticleTitle")
@Expose
private String articleTitle;
@SerializedName("ArticleThumb")
@Expose
private String articleThumb;
@SerializedName("ArticleImg")
@Expose
private Object articleImg;
@SerializedName("ArticleTopImg")
@Expose
private String articleTopImg;
@SerializedName("ArticleSum")
@Expose
private String articleSum;
@SerializedName("ArticleExtUrl")
@Expose
private String articleExtUrl;
@SerializedName("CommentCnt")
@Expose
private String commentCnt;
@SerializedName("ReplyCnt")
@Expose
private String replyCnt;
@SerializedName("ArticleCreatedBy")
@Expose
private String articleCreatedBy;
@SerializedName("ArticleModDt")
@Expose
private String articleModDt;
@SerializedName("ArticleCreatedDt")
@Expose
private String articleCreatedDt;
@SerializedName("ArticleTotalRating")
@Expose
private String articleTotalRating;
@SerializedName("ArticleRatingCnt")
@Expose
private String articleRatingCnt;
@SerializedName("ArticleViewCnt")
@Expose
private String articleViewCnt;
@SerializedName("UsrFileID")
@Expose
private Object usrFileID;
@SerializedName("GroupID")
@Expose
private String groupID;
@SerializedName("GroupAddTyp")
@Expose
private String groupAddTyp;
@SerializedName("ArticleAddTyp")
@Expose
private String articleAddTyp;
@SerializedName("meta")
@Expose
private String meta;
@SerializedName("meta_image")
@Expose
private String metaImage;
@SerializedName("ArticleSubType")
@Expose
private Object articleSubType;
@SerializedName("Language")
@Expose
private String language;
@SerializedName("Attachment")
@Expose
private List<Object> attachment = new ArrayList<Object>();
@SerializedName("TopicNm")
@Expose
private String topicNm;
@SerializedName("TagNm")
@Expose
private List<TagNm> tagNm = new ArrayList<TagNm>();
@SerializedName("ArticleTopImgThumb")
@Expose
private String articleTopImgThumb;
@SerializedName("ReadTime")
@Expose
private Integer readTime;
@SerializedName("UsrPicture")
@Expose
private String usrPicture;
@SerializedName("LikeFlag")
@Expose
private Integer likeFlag;
@SerializedName("Likes")
@Expose
private Integer likes;
@SerializedName("isFavourite")
@Expose
private String isFavourite;

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleID
*/
public String getArticleID() {
return articleID;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleID
* The ArticleID
*/
public void setArticleID(String articleID) {
this.articleID = articleID;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The topicID
*/
public String getTopicID() {
return topicID;
}

/**
* 
* @param topicID
* The TopicID
*/
public void setTopicID(String topicID) {
this.topicID = topicID;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The entID
*/
public String getEntID() {
return entID;
}

/**
* 
* @param entID
* The EntID
*/
public void setEntID(String entID) {
this.entID = entID;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The compID
*/
public String getCompID() {
return compID;
}

/**
* 
* @param compID
* The CompID
*/
public void setCompID(String compID) {
this.compID = compID;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleOwnerUsrID
*/
public String getArticleOwnerUsrID() {
return articleOwnerUsrID;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleOwnerUsrID
* The ArticleOwnerUsrID
*/
public void setArticleOwnerUsrID(String articleOwnerUsrID) {
this.articleOwnerUsrID = articleOwnerUsrID;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleType
*/
public String getArticleType() {
return articleType;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleType
* The ArticleType
*/
public void setArticleType(String articleType) {
this.articleType = articleType;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleTitle
*/
public String getArticleTitle() {
return articleTitle;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleTitle
* The ArticleTitle
*/
public void setArticleTitle(String articleTitle) {
this.articleTitle = articleTitle;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleThumb
*/
public String getArticleThumb() {
return articleThumb;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleThumb
* The ArticleThumb
*/
public void setArticleThumb(String articleThumb) {
this.articleThumb = articleThumb;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleImg
*/
public Object getArticleImg() {
return articleImg;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleImg
* The ArticleImg
*/
public void setArticleImg(Object articleImg) {
this.articleImg = articleImg;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleTopImg
*/
public String getArticleTopImg() {
return articleTopImg;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleTopImg
* The ArticleTopImg
*/
public void setArticleTopImg(String articleTopImg) {
this.articleTopImg = articleTopImg;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleSum
*/
public String getArticleSum() {
return articleSum;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleSum
* The ArticleSum
*/
public void setArticleSum(String articleSum) {
this.articleSum = articleSum;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleExtUrl
*/
public String getArticleExtUrl() {
return articleExtUrl;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleExtUrl
* The ArticleExtUrl
*/
public void setArticleExtUrl(String articleExtUrl) {
this.articleExtUrl = articleExtUrl;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The commentCnt
*/
public String getCommentCnt() {
return commentCnt;
}

/**
* 
* @param commentCnt
* The CommentCnt
*/
public void setCommentCnt(String commentCnt) {
this.commentCnt = commentCnt;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The replyCnt
*/
public String getReplyCnt() {
return replyCnt;
}

/**
* 
* @param replyCnt
* The ReplyCnt
*/
public void setReplyCnt(String replyCnt) {
this.replyCnt = replyCnt;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleCreatedBy
*/
public String getArticleCreatedBy() {
return articleCreatedBy;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleCreatedBy
* The ArticleCreatedBy
*/
public void setArticleCreatedBy(String articleCreatedBy) {
this.articleCreatedBy = articleCreatedBy;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleModDt
*/
public String getArticleModDt() {
return articleModDt;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleModDt
* The ArticleModDt
*/
public void setArticleModDt(String articleModDt) {
this.articleModDt = articleModDt;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleCreatedDt
*/
public String getArticleCreatedDt() {
return articleCreatedDt;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleCreatedDt
* The ArticleCreatedDt
*/
public void setArticleCreatedDt(String articleCreatedDt) {
this.articleCreatedDt = articleCreatedDt;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleTotalRating
*/
public String getArticleTotalRating() {
return articleTotalRating;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleTotalRating
* The ArticleTotalRating
*/
public void setArticleTotalRating(String articleTotalRating) {
this.articleTotalRating = articleTotalRating;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleRatingCnt
*/
public String getArticleRatingCnt() {
return articleRatingCnt;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleRatingCnt
* The ArticleRatingCnt
*/
public void setArticleRatingCnt(String articleRatingCnt) {
this.articleRatingCnt = articleRatingCnt;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleViewCnt
*/
public String getArticleViewCnt() {
return articleViewCnt;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleViewCnt
* The ArticleViewCnt
*/
public void setArticleViewCnt(String articleViewCnt) {
this.articleViewCnt = articleViewCnt;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The usrFileID
*/
public Object getUsrFileID() {
return usrFileID;
}

/**
* 
* @param usrFileID
* The UsrFileID
*/
public void setUsrFileID(Object usrFileID) {
this.usrFileID = usrFileID;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The groupID
*/
public String getGroupID() {
return groupID;
}

/**
* 
* @param groupID
* The GroupID
*/
public void setGroupID(String groupID) {
this.groupID = groupID;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The groupAddTyp
*/
public String getGroupAddTyp() {
return groupAddTyp;
}

/**
* 
* @param groupAddTyp
* The GroupAddTyp
*/
public void setGroupAddTyp(String groupAddTyp) {
this.groupAddTyp = groupAddTyp;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleAddTyp
*/
public String getArticleAddTyp() {
return articleAddTyp;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleAddTyp
* The ArticleAddTyp
*/
public void setArticleAddTyp(String articleAddTyp) {
this.articleAddTyp = articleAddTyp;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The meta
*/
public String getMeta() {
return meta;
}

/**
* 
* @param meta
* The meta
*/
public void setMeta(String meta) {
this.meta = meta;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The metaImage
*/
public String getMetaImage() {
return metaImage;
}

/**
* 
* @param metaImage
* The meta_image
*/
public void setMetaImage(String metaImage) {
this.metaImage = metaImage;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleSubType
*/
public Object getArticleSubType() {
return articleSubType;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleSubType
* The ArticleSubType
*/
public void setArticleSubType(Object articleSubType) {
this.articleSubType = articleSubType;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The language
*/
public String getLanguage() {
return language;
}

/**
* 
* @param language
* The Language
*/
public void setLanguage(String language) {
this.language = language;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The attachment
*/
public List<Object> getAttachment() {
return attachment;
}

/**
* 
* @param attachment
* The Attachment
*/
public void setAttachment(List<Object> attachment) {
this.attachment = attachment;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The topicNm
*/
public String getTopicNm() {
return topicNm;
}

/**
* 
* @param topicNm
* The TopicNm
*/
public void setTopicNm(String topicNm) {
this.topicNm = topicNm;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The tagNm
*/
public List<TagNm> getTagNm() {
return tagNm;
}

/**
* 
* @param tagNm
* The TagNm
*/
public void setTagNm(List<TagNm> tagNm) {
this.tagNm = tagNm;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleTopImgThumb
*/
public String getArticleTopImgThumb() {
return articleTopImgThumb;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleTopImgThumb
* The ArticleTopImgThumb
*/
public void setArticleTopImgThumb(String articleTopImgThumb) {
this.articleTopImgThumb = articleTopImgThumb;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The readTime
*/
public Integer getReadTime() {
return readTime;
}

/**
* 
* @param readTime
* The ReadTime
*/
public void setReadTime(Integer readTime) {
this.readTime = readTime;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The usrPicture
*/
public String getUsrPicture() {
return usrPicture;
}

/**
* 
* @param usrPicture
* The UsrPicture
*/
public void setUsrPicture(String usrPicture) {
this.usrPicture = usrPicture;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The likeFlag
*/
public Integer getLikeFlag() {
return likeFlag;
}

/**
* 
* @param likeFlag
* The LikeFlag
*/
public void setLikeFlag(Integer likeFlag) {
this.likeFlag = likeFlag;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The likes
*/
public Integer getLikes() {
return likes;
}

/**
* 
* @param likes
* The Likes
*/
public void setLikes(Integer likes) {
this.likes = likes;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The isFavourite
*/
public String getIsFavourite() {
return isFavourite;
}

/**
* 
* @param isFavourite
* The isFavourite
*/
public void setIsFavourite(String isFavourite) {
this.isFavourite = isFavourite;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = new ArrayList<Datum>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The status
*/
public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

/**
* 
* @param status
* The status
*/
public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The data
*/
public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

/**
* 
* @param data
* The data
*/
public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.TagNm.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


public class TagNm {

@SerializedName("ArticleID")
@Expose
private String articleID;
@SerializedName("TagID")
@Expose
private String tagID;
@SerializedName("TagNm")
@Expose
private String tagNm;

/**
* 
* @return
* The articleID
*/
public String getArticleID() {
return articleID;
}

/**
* 
* @param articleID
* The ArticleID
*/
public void setArticleID(String articleID) {
this.articleID = articleID;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The tagID
*/
public String getTagID() {
return tagID;
}

/**
* 
* @param tagID
* The TagID
*/
public void setTagID(String tagID) {
this.tagID = tagID;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The tagNm
*/
public String getTagNm() {
return tagNm;
}

/**
* 
* @param tagNm
* The TagNm
*/
public void setTagNm(String tagNm) {
this.tagNm = tagNm;
}

}
```

Comment: its working thanks thanks then how to check null values is need or not

Comment: from web service response , there is no need to check null value if response has no key then that will be skip automatically